# Stream data (such as music) using PHP (or another language)

Tags: php, sockets, mp3, stream

For years, I've been investigating how to create music streams from my computer.  I've seen programs, but anything useful I've seen is Windows only (I use a Mac).

Eventually, I got interested in *how* streams work.  Is there any way I could create my *own* stream, possibly using socket functions in `PHP`?  Is there a `PHP` library for this?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Ampache](http://ampache.org/). It is a Web-based Open Source Audio file manager. It is implemented with MySQL, and PHP. It allows you to view, edit, and play your audio files via the web.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it all boils down to the protocol you'd want to use. Shoutcast IMHO is plain HTTP, so to *make* your own stream, you just output the streams content.

To make an ogg based webradio work with my Sonos system, I have created a little transcoding wrapper around sox which is is actually written in PHP, so it may be helpful to you to serve as an example.

You'll find it here: http://www.gnegg.ch/ogg2mp3/

If you are after implementing your very own streaming protocol - maybe even UDP based, then, I'm afraid, PHP may not be the right solution for the problem - at least not as long as it has its share of problems when used for long running processes (which 5.3 may bring some help for with its integrated garbage collection)