# A PHP script to stream internet radio?

Tags: php, streaming, internet-radio

I've been searching and searching and I haven't yet come up with a solution to host my own streaming audio player.

I'm looking for a way to host an internet radio player that connects to whatever streams I enter in and plays them. I'm not looking to play my MP3s or anything like that. I'm looking to play content from 181.fm or 1Club.fm, for example. I'd even settle for ShoutCast-only streams.

I've been to www.wavestreaming.com but it didnt work for me. I'm guessing its because in the very first box where you enter your website url, it leads in for you: http//www.   then you fill in the rest. My site is https:// and does not contain a www. in the URL. I'm guessing that has something to do with it.

Any links, suggestions for search topics, or even a brief technical overview of what I should be looking into would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048370/techs-needed-for-building-a-online-radio-website and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166/stream-data-such-as-music-using-php-or-another-language

Comment: Ah. It seems I was using the wrong search terms because I did not come across those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install winamp shoutcast server to your server. Download link is here : http://classic.shoutcast.com/download/serve.phtml You can control server via PHP with shell_exec() and fsockopen() function.

Comment: also http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5317-PHP-Implement-a-Shoutcast-music-streaming-server.html this class may be help you